# Fill gap between a counter and a stainless steam table

Tags: gap, steam

I need to fill gap between a composite counter  that is surrounding a stainless steam table tub. The gap is 1/4" to 3/8", the steam table gets hot, 400 degree silicone has not worked. It shrinks and comes loose after a short time period.

Whatever is used must be ready for service after a 12 hour application period. The material must be able to be cleaned off of the counter and stainless surfaces after the gap is filled and it must be white.

Is Acrylic grout a possibility?

Comment: Refractory caulk or a stainless steel counter/stove gap cover.

Comment: Use high heat resistant epoxy, which can stands temperature 600 F and up.